# How to implement the segment function in GEKKO?

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I am trying to model and solve a nonlinear optimization problem through GEKKO.
The objective function is like:

```
m.Minimize(k*(w1*abs(x0-L10)+w2*abs(x1-L20))+β*Dindf[0]*(w1*alpha_beta(x0)+w2*alpha_beta(x1)+w1***alpha_beta**(x2)+w2*alpha_beta(x3)) +\
                k*(w1*abs(x2-x0) + w2*abs(x3-x1)+w1*abs(x4-x2) + w2*abs(x5-x3)))
```

The problem is I need the alpha_beta(x) function(wrt to the decision variables, shown as follows) to be a segment form, how can I code this function so that I can solve the problem?

```
def alpha_beta(x):
    a = 0.0019727939
    b = 0.0078887
    Lmin, Lnom, Lmax = 0.8035, 2.3811, 3.084
    return np.piecewise(x, [np.logical_and(Lmin <= x, x < Lnom),
                            np.logical_and(Lnom <= x, x <= Lmax)],
                        [lambda x: a * ((x - Lnom)**2) + 0.006226,
                         lambda x: b * ((x - Lnom)**2) + 0.006226, 0])
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `m.if3()` Gekko function to use a different function based on the value of `x`. Also, replace the `abs()` function in the objective function with the Gekko version of `m.abs2()` or `m.abs3()` (preferred). Here is an example script.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()
x = m.Var(lb=0.8035,ub=3.084)

def alpha_beta(x):
    a = 0.0019727939
    b = 0.0078887
    Lnom = 2.3811
    e1 = a*(x-Lnom)**2 + 0.006226
    e2 = b*(x-Lnom)**2 + 0.006226
    return m.if3(x-Lnom,e1,e2)
    
m.Minimize(alpha_beta(x)+m.abs3(-x))

m.solve()
```

This produces the solution `x=0.8035`.

```
 Number of state variables:              9
 Number of total equations: -            6
 Number of slack variables: -            4
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :             -1
 
 * Warning: DOF <= 0
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter: 1 I: 0 Tm: 0.00 NLPi: 3 Dpth: 0 Lvs: 0 Obj: 8.15E-01 Gap: 0.00E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   1.290000000153668E-002 sec
 Objective      :   0.814635932386315     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the instruction, Professor Hedengren. I am going to try this implementation on my problem.

Comment: Professor Hedengren, I have a small question about m.abs3(). Is it serve the same function as in math abs()? I do not understand why I get 0 for the following results? m=GEKKO() m.abs3(-2), m.abs3(2

Comment: The solution is symbolic until the `m.solve()` function is called. Try running this script: `from gekko import GEKKO; m = GEKKO(); y = m.Var(); m.Equation(y==m.abs3(-2)); m.solve(); print(y.value[0])` to get an answer of `2`.

Comment: It works, thank you very much!